# Constraint Layout missing atributes (no atributes at all)

Tags: layout, constraints

I have a problem with my Constraint Layout: when I introduce a new button or text field or anything like that, the Constraint Layout appears but i cannot change any atribute valor, including the name of the button/texto/anything.

I had a problem with the SDK Manager location and fixed it (by creating a new location and setting the path to it) then I had a problem with Gradle which was fixed as well but now i have this problem…

I've already unistalled and installed Android Studio again, not the solution.

It looks like this:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCrTD.png)

---

This is the full error code I get in the report:

null
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.EmptyProperty.getModel(EmptyProperty.java:106)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.BrowsePanel.getBrowser(BrowsePanel.java:224)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.BrowsePanel.showBrowseDialog(BrowsePanel.java:208)
        at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.BrowsePanel$BrowseAction.actionPerformed(BrowsePanel.java:175)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:195)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:153)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:346)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.EmptyProperty.getModel(EmptyProperty.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.BrowsePanel.getBrowser(BrowsePanel.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.BrowsePanel.showBrowseDialog(BrowsePanel.java:208)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.editors.BrowsePanel$BrowseAction.actionPerformed(BrowsePanel.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:346)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

---

Please help
Thanks

Comment: I found out that in res>layout I only have the "activity_main.xml" and no "content_main.xml" . creating a new "folder" and copying the code into it or copying a "contente_main.xml" from another coputer did not work.